# How to setup VS Code project for LLVM building

Tags: c++, llvm, visual-studio-code

I want to use VS Code for building & debugging LLVM source code. Is there a good document which explains how to setup project in VS Code for LLVM ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the below blog useful :
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2021/04/22/remote-llvm-development-with-visual-studio-code#

This talks about remote SSH setup, but all these things can be easily replicated with native vscode install.

Comment: Also, here's another useful post https://www.linaro.org/blog/how-to-set-up-vs-code-for-llvm-development/