# Switch Apple clang to Homebrew clang in VS code configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

I have 2 versions of clang in my system. One installed using brew and another one it was required by XCode (which is set by default and referred as "Apple clang"). Previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64225495/how-to-switch-from-apple-to-homebrew-installed-clang), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947981/how-to-setup-vs-code-project-for-llvm-building) or guides [[1]](https://nkaushik.com/ide/vscode-cpp-11-mac/vscode-cpp-11-mac/), [[2]](https://www.40tude.fr/compile-cpp-code-with-vscode-clang/), [[3]](https://dev.to/ethanmgustafson/c-environment-configuration-vs-code-macos-30ga) weren't useful for me.

BTW brew noted clang/llvm as a "keg-only" package. I've uninstalled xcode-tools, but for example later when I used otool a xcode window popped requiring to install xcode-tools... Anyway, I have this setup right now:

```
/usr/bin/clang <--- This one installed by XCode tools
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/<version>/bin/clang <---- This one installed by homebrew
```

Now I am in a situation where I want to compile with the clang version installed by homebrew using VS code, but I didn't found any config files to switch from xcode clang to "homebrew" clang.

These are my config files so far:

*tasks.json (manually changed command entry)*

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "command": "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/bin/clang",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/bin/clang"
        }
    ]
}
```

*c_cpp_properties.json*

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/include/**",
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/local/bin/gcc-11",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

*A sample version.c file*

```
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void show_clang_version(void) {
        CXString version = clang_getClangVersion();
        printf("%s\n", clang_getCString(version));
        clang_disposeString(version);
}

int main( int argc, const char *const * argv )
{
        show_clang_version();
        return 0;
}
```

**This is the error I get**

```
Starting build...
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/13.0.1_1/bin/clang -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/bel/libclang-test/vs-project/version.c -o /Users/bel/libclang-test/vs-project/version
/Users/bel/libclang-test/vs-project/version.c:1:10: fatal error: 'clang-c/Index.h' file not found
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Comment: did you make sure to follow all the instructions given by the messages printed while installing llvm via homebrew? There's some stuff about `LD_PRELOAD` iirc.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?